# Token with expiration date in Corda?

Tags: corda

How would you design a Fungible token that expires in Corda (in both state design and flow design)? A token that cannot be used anymore once the expiration date has passed, and it consequently becomes historic once the expiration is detected in the flow.

Any idea is welcome. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

- Extend `FungibleToken` and add an expiration date field (of type `Instant`).
- Extend the contract so that:

  - A rule expects the `Move` and `Redeem` commands to have a time-window included in the transaction.
  - The time-window's "until time" should be less than the expiration date.
- Inside your flow, you should add a time-window to the transaction of `Move` or `Redeem`. When the notary receives the transaction it will either accept it or reject it based on if it received it within the supplied time-window; meaning if you said that the time-window is from now until 1 minute; basically you're telling the notary, only accept this transaction if you received it within "now + 1 minute" (so basically your flow should be able to sign locally, verify, and collect signatures within 1 minute -the 1 minute is just an example, you can set the time-window to whatever you want-).
- The notary is the time-stamping authority, so if the notary accepted your transaction; it means that it attests that your transaction was received at a certain time (before the token's expiration date).
- You can read about time-windows (an explanation, an exercise, and a solution) [here](https://training.corda.net/corda-details/time-windows/).

Comment: Thank you, @adel-rustum. Adding here also the second approach suggested on Slack, using SchedulableState in Corda 4.6. "You can implementSchedulableState to "expire" to token automatically based on the supplied time (https://docs.corda.net/docs/corda-os/4.6/event-scheduling.html)
To expire it, I guess you can pass it as input and not create an output? That will make it unspendable."

Comment: `SchedulableState` is used to automate things; meaning when that state is consumed, it triggers some action. The suggestion of passing it as an input and not creating an output, means you're redeeming that token; redeeming a token has liability implications. When an issuer issues a token to you, it's a promise from them to give you the equivalent of that token off-chain when you redeem it on-chain.

Comment: The way that I understood your requirement is that once the token expires, you shouldn't be able to do any command against it (including `Redeem`).

Comment: thank you for the clarification, @adel-rustum. You understood my requirement correctly. SchedulableState is definitely something else.

Comment: @AdelRustum The time-window approach makes sense as well (better depending on the use-case). I feel a "burn" command can have different sematics to "move" to avoid wrong interpretation. A question: For querying, is there a way to filter states whose time windows have expired? I (owner,  as well as any other observers) don't want to see tokens that are effectively useless because the window has expired (or try to accidentally attempt to spend such tokens.)

Comment: It's as simple as creating a custom schema for your state, then you create a custom query criteria "where expirationDate > now"; this way you get the unexpired states as of now.